# Undefined class constant 'FETCH_ASSCOC' while connecting to database with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, pdo

This is the line, where I get error with:

```
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSCOC,
```

there is the full code:

```
<?php

class CON {

public static function db() {

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$db = "4";
$user = "danny";
$password = "censored";
$charset = "utf8";

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSCOC,
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES      => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

}

}

?>
```

Comment: Just a typo, it should be `FETCH_ASSOC,`

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead of `PDO::FETCH_ASSCOC` - full list of available fetch types: http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: Ahahahah, I'm so stupid, thanks anyway.

Comment: Is this a front loading error or a backend loading error